# Why constructor is not invoked when we use this keyword in Java?

Tags: java

'this'keyword refers to the instance of current class. So during the creation of instance of the class default constructor of the class must be called right? Like in this example.
Please do help me with this as I didn't found the answer to this question anywhere.

```
class Foo
{
    int x = 100;
    Foo obj = this;//Does it creates new instance of class or refers to calling object

    Foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }

    Foo(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;// Why default constructor not invoked ? 
    }

    void print()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    Foo ret()
    {
        return obj;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo obj = new Foo(10);
        obj.print(); //prints 10
        Foo xyz = obj.ret();
        xyz.print(); //Also prints 10
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think it should be called?

Comment: You have to call it yourself: `this();`.

Comment: Do not name your class `This`, not unless you want to confuse others and your future self.

Comment: Please can you help me with question inside the code too 

Comment: Naming your class 'This' is really against the convention. Please use a proper name for your class

Comment: Terminology: The *default constructor* only exists in classes which do not define any constructor themselves. While the *default constructor* is a *no-arg* constructor, it is incorrect to refer to an explicitly defined *no-arg* constructor as the *default constructor*.

Answer (score 3):

> Why default constructor not invoked ?

A constructor which doesn't explicitly invoke another constructor will invoke `super()` - the no-arg constructor of the superclass. This may not exist (and would result in a compiler error if not), but does in the case of `Object`.

From [JLS 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

`this()` isn't invoked because it's assumed that `This(int)` is capable of fully initializing the `This` instance. In general, `This()` and `This(int)` might do conflicting (or duplicative) things, so you wouldn't want to always invoke `This()` from `This(int)`.

If you want `this()` to be invoked, invoke it.

---

> ```
> //Does it creates new instance of class or refers to calling object
> ```

If it created a new instance of the class, that would create a new instance, which has a field that would be initialized to a new instance of the class. That, in turn, would have a field that would be initialized to a new instance of the class... You'd get a `StackOverflowError`

It refers to the current instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you help me with the other question too

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the default constructor to initialise the object.
You used the constructor

```
Foo obj = new Foo(10);
```

Which would initialise the object using the method

```
Foo(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `Foo obj = this;` refers the instance created when `Foo obj = new Foo(10);` is executed. In simple words both the variables named `obj` inside and outside the class hold the same instance that is why you are able to print 10 in both the cases. Write `this();` method inside the parameterized constructor to invoke the default constructor of Foo class. Remember it will not create another instance though.

Comment: It won't invoke the default constructor since Foo doesn't have a default constructor. It has a *no-arg* constructor, which is similar, but is not the default constructor. The default constructor only exists in classes which do not define any constructor.

Comment: I totally agree with your context @DavidConrad but it was mentioned as "Why default constructor not invoked ?". That is the reason for me stating it as default constructor and to make sure the person asked the question has a clear view.